# Package Visibility in new Google Play Privacy Policy

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, android-11

I read [this link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779?hl=en) about the Google play new privacy policy. But I don't understand. Can I keep the below line without adding permission to AndroidManifest.xml and get a filtered list of device applications?
And can I keep this line without adding `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission to AndroidManifest.xml and set the condition to get installed apps on the device for android ten and below? Both of them without adding anything to my Google Play store Privacy policy.

```
context.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I keep the below line without adding permission to AndroidManifest.xml and get a filtered list of device applications?

You can keep the line without modifications. However, `getInstalledApplications()` will not return many items. It will mostly return pre-installed applications, not user-installed applications. I do not know if that matches your "get a filtered list of device applications".

> And can I keep this line without adding QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission to AndroidManifest.xml and set the condition to get installed apps on the device for android ten and below?

I do not know what "set the condition" means here. On Android 10 and below, `getInstalledApplications()` should return all installed applications.

Comment: Thanks for your response. About your first question, I mean get pre-installed applications as you said.
About your second question, I mean I add the below condition to my app programmatically, and Google Play doesn't suspend my app because I don't have QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission in my AndroidManifest.

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q

Comment: @BehroozFard: Google *wants* you to *not* have `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`. However, if you feel that your app requires `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`, you need to get Google to agree. So, if you can write your app and avoid `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`, you should be fine.

Comment: Would you please share with me google docs about these topics?

Comment: @BehroozFard: Well, you already linked to [one](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779?hl=en). That entire document is about what happens if you *request* `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`. Beyond that, there is [this](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/automatic), [this](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring), [this](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases), and [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9) for package visibility overall.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got my answer. But I want to ask another question. Do you know why we get user-installed applications instead of pre-installed applications on android 11 without adding QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES to AndroidManifest? When will google apply this policy to return pre-installed applications?

Comment: @BehroozFard: "When will google apply this policy to return pre-installed applications? " -- it already has this policy applied, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 30 or higher.