# Google Play Policy for Package Visibility for pre-android 11

Tags: java, android, google-play

I read [this link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10446026) and this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67251263/package-visibility-in-new-google-play-privacy-policy) but there is something I don't understand.

I have this line of code in my app `packageManager.getInstalledPackages(flag)`, However i'm not using the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission which is understandable that I will not be able to receive the user installed packages, that's not an issue as of now for me. However, The first link stated that:

> The inventory of installed apps queried from a device are regarded as personal and sensitive user data

So will using this method `packageManager.getInstalledPackages(flag)` consider a violation and cause my app to be removed from the play store?

Thanks for your time and input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following method

```
packageManager.getInstalledPackages(flag)
```

will not be considered as violations. However this in android 11 will only give you list of packages of open apps to user.